# Задача на седловые точки Pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Дана целочисленная матрица n x m. Написать программу, определяющую номера строк и столбцов всех седловых точек матрицы ().
Матрица А имеет седловую точку Аij, если Аij является минимальным элементом в i-ой строке и максимальным в j-м столбце.
Количество элементов массива вводится пользователем, заполняется случайными числами из диапазона: от -2018 до 2017.

```
    var 
  numberOfArrayI: integer;
  numberOfArrayJ: integer;
  i, j: integer;
  arr: array of array of integer;
  maxl, minl: array of integer;
  maxr, minr: array of integer;
begin
  assign(input, 'input.txt');
  reset(input);
  read(input, numberOfArrayI);
  read(input, numberOfArrayJ);
  close(input);


  for i:=1 to numberOfArrayI do
    begin
      for j:=1 to numberOfArrayJ do
      begin
        arr[i,j]:=Random(-2018, 2017);
      end
    end;

  for i:=1 to numberOfArrayI do
  begin
    maxr[i]:= arr[i, 1];
    minr[i]:= arr[i, 1];

  end;
  for j:= 1 to numberOfArrayJ do
  begin
    maxl[j]:= arr[1, j];
    minl[j]:= arr[1, j];
  end;
  for i:= 1 to numberOfArrayI do
    for j:= 1 to numberOfArrayJ do
    begin
      if arr[i, j] > maxr[i] then
        maxr[i]:= arr[i, j]
      else if arr[i, j] < minr[i] then
        minr[i]:= arr[i, j];
      if arr[i, j] > maxl[j] then
        maxl[j]:= arr[i, j]
      else if arr[i, j] < minl[j] then
        minl[j]:= arr[i, j];
    end;



end.
```

Как мне теперь вывести седловые точки? Пытаюсь WriteLn(maxr) и т.д., но нечего не выводит :/

Answer (score 0):

```
program points;
var
  n, m: integer;
  a: array of array of integer;
  i, j: integer;
  cols, rows: array of integer;
  min, max: integer;
begin
  write('N: ');
  readln(n);
  write('M: ');
  readln(m);

  SetLength(cols, m);
  SetLength(rows, n);
  SetLength(a, n);
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    SetLength(a[i], m);

  Randomize;
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to m - 1 do
      a[i][j] := Random(-2018, 2017);
  end;

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    min := a[i][0];
    rows[i] := 0;
    for j := 1 to m - 1 do
    begin
      if min > a[i][j] then
       begin
         min := a[i][j];
         rows[i] := j;
       end;
    end;
  end;

  for j := 0 to m - 1 do
  begin
    max := a[0][j];
    cols[j] := 0;
    for i := 1 to n - 1 do
    begin
      if max < a[i][j] then
       begin
         max := a[i][j];
         cols[j] := i;
       end;
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to m - 1 do
      write(a[i][j]:6);
    writeln();
  end;

  writeln('Седловые точки:');
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
  begin
    if cols[rows[i]] = i then
      writeln(i:2, rows[i]:2);
  end;
end.
```

Результат:

```
N: 5
M: 3
 -1793  1786  1515
  1502  -944 -1413
  1325  -888 -1531
  1150  1943  -786
 -1503  1346    97
Седловые точки:

N: 5
M: 6
  -148  -639  1123  -665  1943   412
   479  -233   629  -280  1215   797
 -1705 -1291  1629 -1284   332  1932
  1292  1389  1209   412  1517   540
 -1761  1467  2012   317   160  1433
Седловые точки:
 3 3
```

Код не сработает если в строке минимальное число повторится больше одного раза, и оно же будет являться максимальным в нескольких столбцах.